# r distinct balls in N boxes

Tags: probability

**If r distinct balls are distributed at random into N (N ≤ r) boxes, what is the probability that box 1 will receive exactly j balls ( 0 ≤  ≤ r)?**

---

my solution is 
[sample space] =$ N^r $

$$P=\frac{ 1}{N^r}\binom{r}{j}$$

I know there is something wrong. can you help me ?

Comment: @leonbloy, is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

You have the sample space correct. We calculate how many ways there are to place the balls so that $j$ are in box $1$.

- Let's first pick $j$ balls from the $r$. There are ${{r}\choose{j}}$
  ways to do that.
- There is only $1$ way to place these $r$ balls since they must all go
  in box $1$.
- *Here is the part you are missing*: For the remaining $r-j$ balls, we can place them each $N-1$ ways. We have $(N-1)^{(r-j)}$ ways to
  replace these remaining balls.

Now we multiply it all together. We have:

$${{r}\choose{j}}(N-1)^{(r-j)} $$

The probability is:

$$\frac{{{r}\choose{j}}(N-1)^{(r-j)}}{N^r}$$

Comment: why we are calculating (r - j)? I mean why are writing it $(N - 1)^(r-j)$

Comment: $r-j$ is the number of balls not in box $1$. There are $N-1$ ways to place each of these balls. So, the number of ways to place all $r-j$ of these is $(N-1)^{(r-j)}$

Answer (score 4):

CommonerG's answer is right. Another approach is considering it as a Binomial experiment: each ball is a try, when it falls into box 1 it's a success (prob=$1/N$), you are interested in getting $j$ successes. Then

$$ P = \binom{r}{j} \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^j \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{r-j}$$